# How to get into devops engineer role and what about openings

Tags: devops

I have some gap after my academics. i heard devops is good right now in IT industry. Can i proceed with learning devops is it good for my career?
And also wandering about job openings for devops engineer role.what is the career for devops .How much package i can expect for devops engineer ?

Comment: I would go for programmer, instead of devops, but that's just my opinion. I don't have any sources to back it up.

Comment: The average salary for a DevOps Engineer in Chicago is $112,192 according to google search.